# g++ permission denied(Mac)

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, permission-denied

I tried to run a c++ file with the mac terminal, but it gave me the error as shown below:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Where did the `test` file come from? Last I checked, GCC names the output `a.out` by default.

Comment: I did "ls" in the terminal and saw a file titled "test'. I thought it was the result of doing "g++-10 test.cpp", but it turns out to be another file with the same name, not related to test.cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do this `gcc test.cpp` you will get executable called `a.out`, and to run it you type:

```
./a.out
```

to get executable called `test` you have to run `g++ test.cpp -o test` now you can run this:

```
./test
```

Comment: ah I see. Is the default name always a? Also, what happens if there is already an "a.out" in the directory your in? Will that one be replaced?

Comment: @timg yes it will be replaced